# How can I generate a random number that is one of the set [ 0,5,10,15]?

Tags: c#

I have been using the following:

```
Random r = new Random(); 
var a = r.Next(9)
```

To generate a random number between 0-9.

However now I need to generate one of the following numbers at random: 0,5,10,15

Is there a way that I could modify this just to select the numbers above?

Answer (score 6):

```
Random r = new Random(); 
var a = r.Next(4) * 5;
```

Will do the trick. Note that the argument is an *exclusive* upper bound, so it won't ever be generated. Your code sample generates between 0 and 8.

If you need a different set of numbers, you could do the following:

```
int[] possible = new int[] { 0, 5, 10, 15 };
Random r = new Random(); 
int a = possible[r.Next(possible.length)];
```

Comment: Aaaand I'm downvoted as well. Explanation? Three posts in here have been downvoted with no reason given.

Comment: The downvote could be from someone hoping to increase exposure on their own answer

Comment: That would be my guess as well, considering the sheer number of them. Unfortunate that someone would do that.

Answer (score 4):

```
Random rnd = new Random();

//create a pre-defined list
int[] nums = new int[] {0, 5, 10, 15};

int rndNum = nums[rnd.Next(nums.Length)];
```

You can even repeate the loop to generate more then one random number from the set of per-defined numbers in an array.

Comment: Note that `Next`'s argument is an *exclusive* upper bound.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I've had it happen because of syntax errors before. You've got several in there, so that's possible. EDIT: TGH got hit, too, so I guess not. This is an odd post. EDIT2: And me as well. What is this madness?

Comment: @MikePrecup - well syntax fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Put the four numbers into an array of four elements.
Then generate random numbers between 0-3 and use that to index the array

Comment: This is essentially the same as @AppDeveloper's solution. Only the code is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a random number between 0 and 3, then simply use that as an index into an array:

Something like this (pseudocode):

```
var nums = [0, 5, 10, 15];
return nums[new Random().Next(4)];
```

Or if it really is as simple as multiples of 5; simple multiply it:

```
return new Random().Next(4) * 5;
```

Comment: `Next(3)` will only yield 0, 1, or 2

Answer (score 0):

```
const int iterator = 5;
const int upperBound = 15;

var possibleValues = (from n in Enumerable.Range(0, upperBound + 1)
                      where n % iterator == 0
                      select n).ToArray(); 

Random r = new Random();
var a = possibleValues[r.Next(possibleValues.Length)];
```

Comment: Add comma between 10 and 15.

Comment: `if (i % iterator == 0)` -- it would be better (faster) to increment `i` by `iterator`. Or, for elegance, you could probably do this in one line with Linq.

Comment: What would the linq solution look like?

Comment: Found the linq solution. DIdn't know about the Range, nice

Comment: Is there a LINQ solution that doesn't involve the % step?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int count, int start = 0, int step = 1)
{
    for (int i = start; i < count; i++)
        yield return i;
}

var arr = Range(4, 0, 5).ToArray(); // 0, 5, 10, 15.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Random r = new Random();
  var a = r.Next(4)*5;
```